# Accessing files in a child directory in Python 2.7.x

Tags: python, python-2.x, file-system, csv

I have written the below script for use in Python 2.7.x. In essence, I want the script to access a folder contained within the directory the script is and then add all files contained within to a list. I'm then looking to open these files using the csv module and process each line for now.

My script works fine as below but it just seems to be a long-winded way to access the content of files stored in a child directory.

Any suggestions to improve it?

```
import os
import csv

child_files = []
mypath = "./child_directory/"
onlyfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(mypath) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(mypath, f))]
for f in onlyfiles:
    file_path = os.path.relpath(f)
    x = os.path.join(mypath, file_path)
    child_files.append(x)
    print x

for f in child_files:
    with open(f, 'rb') as x:
        reader = csv.reader(x)
        for row in reader:
            print row
```

I'd also be keen to only add '.csv' files contained within the child directory. I can work on this upon a review of my script unless someone can suggest a pythonistic method of incorporating this.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest a generator:

```
def children_files(dir):
    onlyfiles = (f for f in os.listdir(dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir, f)))
    for f in onlyfiles:
        file_path = os.path.relpath(f)
        yield os.path.join(dir, file_path)
```

It is simpler to write (no `append`) and faster as files will be read just as needed.

Answer (score 2):

I would mostly do two things:

1. Use just a generator comprehension, or make a full fledged generator.

   Both are achievable, some people believe comprehensions are the only way to use Python.
   But I think that using an iterative approach here is quite nice.
2. Use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to increase the readability of the code.

   Reading `os.path.function` a lot can be tedious, and has a *negative* impact on performance.

---

```
def child_files(directory):
    prepend_dir = functools.partial(os.path.join, directory)

    for file_name in os.listdir(directory):
        if os.path.isfile(prepend_dir(f)):
            yield prepend_dir(os.path.relpath(file_name))

# Or

prepend_dir = functools.partial(os.path.join, directory)
child_files = (
    prepend_dir(os.path.relpath(file_name))
    for file_name in os.listdir(directory)
    if os.path.isfile(prepend_dir(f))
)
```

---

The second half of your code can be improved by using `file_name` instead of `f`.
This is as `f` is usually used as a file object, and causes the inner file object to be named `x`.
Which can be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting alternative can be using `os.walk`.
`os.walk` is a generator, yielding `root`, `dirs`, `files` values:

- `root` : the base directory it is visiting
- `dirs` : the directories in the directory currently visiting
- `files` : the files in the directory currently visiting

The benefit for you is that `files` already contains only the files,
you don't need to separate them manually as you did in your code.

The only catch is that `os.walk` normally continues to descend into all subdirectories. You can make it stop after the first directory by clearing the content of `dirs`.

Like this:

```
import os
import csv

mypath = "./child_directory/"

def child_files(basedir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(basedir):
        for name in files:
            if name.endswith('.csv'):
                path = os.path.join(root, name)
                yield path
        dirs[:] = []  # don't go to sub-directories

for f in child_files(mypath):
    with open(f, 'rb') as x:
        reader = csv.reader(x)
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
```

Here, `child_files` is a generator, yielding files. I added the filtering of `.csv` files.

Lastly, I suggest using the `print()` function instead of the `print` statement. That way your script will be closer to being Python 3 compatible, and has no downsides for you even if you stick with Python 2.